# Isospectrality vs self-isospectrality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, supersymmetry

I have a confusion in terminology.

What is the difference between two **Isospectral** partner potentials and a potential which is **self-isospectral**?

Context: SUSY QM and Shape invariant, exactly solvable potentials.

Answer (score 0):

For a *self-isospectral potential* the *isospectral partner potential* happens to be the potential itself.

References:

1. F. Cooper, A. Khare, & U. Sukhatme, *Supersymmetry and Quantum Mechanics,* [Phys. Rept. 251 (1995) 267](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(94)00080-M), [arXiv:hep-th/9405029](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405029).

Comment: The terminology seems to originate from G.V. Dunne & J. Feinberg, _Self-Isospectral Periodic Potentials and SUSY QM,_ [arXiv:hep-th/9706012](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9706012).